# Laravel How to return custom error message for newsletter

Tags: php, laravel, newsletter

I'm using the [`spatie/laravel-newsletter`](https://github.com/spatie/laravel-newsletter)-package for my `laravel`-app and I want to make a check if a User already has subscribed for the newsletter. When a user is subscribed I want to return/display a custom error message, like "You have already subscribed" - or something like that, how is that possible?

Here is my check:

```
    if (Newsletter::isSubscribed(request()->email)) {
        // return custom message here?!
    }
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: It's not exactly clear what are you struggling with. Can't you just pass some variable like $alreadySubscribed to the view and conditionally display some message in a blade template?

Answer (score 2):

You could [flash a session variable](https://laravel.com/docs/5.8/redirects#redirecting-with-flashed-session-data) with the error message and display it in your view :

```
if (Newsletter::isSubscribed(request()->email)) {
    return redirect('/your-url')->with('errorIsSubscribed', 'You have already subscribed');
}
```

And then display it in your blade view like so :

```
@if (session('errorIsSubscribed'))
    {{ session('errorIsSubscribed') }}
@endif
```